# difference between chr() and bytes.decode

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone explain why I can convert a `bytes` object to a `str` via

```
>>> bytes_ = b';\xf7\xb8W\xef\x0f\xf4V'
>>> list(bytes_)
[59, 247, 184, 87, 239, 15, 244, 86]
>>> "".join([chr(x) for x in bytes_])
';÷¸Wï\x0fôV'
```

But if I call

```
>>> bytes_.decode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    bytes_.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf7 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I get an error.

Comment: What is origin str?

Comment: encrypted characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default encoding used by `.decode()` is UTF-8. However, at least some bytes in `bytes_` do not correctly encode UTF-8 characters. On the other hand, `chr(n)` returns the n'th Unicode character by its ordinal number, not by encoding. If you want `.decode()` to work, you must tell it which encoding to use. For example, `utf-16` seems to work:

```
bytes_.decode('utf-16')
#'\uf73b垸\u0fef围'
```

`CP1252` works, too, but (expectedly) gives different results:

```
bytes_.decode('cp1252')
#';÷¸Wï\x0fôV'
```

Comment: if all of the bytes are less than 256 shouldn't ascii and utf-8 be able to decode them?

Comment: @user2682863 Only when all bytes are less than 128.

Comment: @user2682863, by definition all byte values are less than 256. ASCII is 7-bit, so it only maps values in the range 0-127. UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding, ranging from 1-4 bytes per character. You cannot decode a byte string as UTF-8 if it contains invalid sequences when consuming the byte string from index 0.